# Submitting SUMMARY Data from Django to React using DRF

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I'm starting to test some API data between django and React using Rest API. I'm able to submit this data between Djnago model and React front end.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "gender": "Male",
        "age": 40,
        "updated": "2022-04-25T18:55:23.304456Z",
        "created": "2022-04-25T14:07:48.282139Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "gender": "Male",
        "age": 33,
        "updated": "2022-04-25T18:55:23.304456Z",
        "created": "2022-04-25T14:07:48.282139Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "gender": "Female",
        "age": 22,
        "updated": "2022-04-25T18:55:23.304456Z",
        "created": "2022-04-25T14:07:48.282139Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "gender": "Female",
        "age": 33,
        "updated": "2022-04-25T18:55:23.304456Z",
        "created": "2022-04-25T14:07:48.282139Z"
    },
]
```

My goal is not to submit this raw data, but instead to submit summary data (data analysis) that calculates the average age for males and females, so I should be getting something like this:

```
[
        {
            "gender": "Male",
            "average_age": 36.5,
        },
        {
            "gender": "Male",
            "average_age": 27.5,
        }
]
```

in TestDrf.js

```
import React from "react"
import axios from 'axios'


export default function App() {

    const [incomingData, setIncomingData] = React.useState([])

    React.useEffect(function() {
        console.log('effect ran')
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/')
            .then(data => setIncomingData(data))
    }, [])
    
    return (
        <div>
            <pre>{JSON.stringify(incomingData.data, null, 2)}</pre>
        </div>
    )
}
```

in views.py

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from .models import Test
from .serializers import TestSerializer

@api_view(['GET'])
def getData(request):
    test_data= Test.objects.all()
    result = Test.objects.values('gender')
                           .annotate(average_age=Avg('age'))
    serializer = TestSerializer(test_data, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Where should I be making these cross tabulations? on the backend or front end?
if on the backend should I be creating new models for the summary data?

I tried looking online for advice on this but I was unlucky!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Django query can be used in the backend to perform [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/); new model is not needed for summary data.

An SQL query for getting average age by gender from a 'person' table would be something like this.

```
SELECT gender, AVG(age) AS average_age
FROM person
GROUP BY gender;
```

The equivalent Django query would be similar to this.

```
from django.db.models import Avg

result = Person.objects.values('gender')
                       .annotate(average_age=Avg('age'))
```

UPDATE: Adding a class based API view

```
class GetData(APIView):
        
    def get(self):
        
        result = Test.objects.values('gender').annotate(average_age=Avg('age'))
        
        response_data = {}
        response_data['data'] = list(result)
        
        return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

urls.py should be updated to use this API view.

```
path('getdata/', GetData.as_view()),
```

Comment: and how do I submit the result from django to react? do I need to skip DRF?

Comment: You'll need an API end-point for the react app to request the average age, and an API view for handling HTTP get request. The get function in this view will run the Django query and return the result as part of HTTP response. I'm assuming you already have this since you can request the raw data from the react app. If not, here's an example - https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/.

Comment: I edited my question to show the get function i currently have in views.py, (in which i added your query), and also included the App function on React's side that is fetching the data from the API, I think now the only missing link is how to add the result as a part of HTTP response

Comment: A few things to note - 'Person' is an example model name that I used since you haven't posted your model. But it looks like your model name is Test. So, you would replace Person.objects.values with Test.objects.values. Also, if the TestSerializer corresponds to your 'Test' model, you can't use it for gender and average_age data. I'll update the answer with an API view example.

Comment: I'm getting this error "TypeError: GetData.get() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Comment: I fixed the error by adding name to def get(self), so now it's def get(self, name), that solved the issue! thanks a billion